# Download, extract and read a gzip file in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to download, extract and iterate over a text file in Python without having to create temporary files.

basically, this pipe, but in python

```
curl ftp://ftp.theseed.org/genomes/SEED/SEED.fasta.gz | gunzip | processing step
```

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    import urllib
    import gzip

    # Download SEED database
    print 'Downloading SEED Database'
    handle = urllib.urlopen('ftp://ftp.theseed.org/genomes/SEED/SEED.fasta.gz')


    with open('SEED.fasta.gz', 'wb') as out:
        while True:
            data = handle.read(1024)
            if len(data) == 0: break
            out.write(data)

    # Extract SEED database
    handle = gzip.open('SEED.fasta.gz')
    with open('SEED.fasta', 'w') as out:
        for line in handle:
            out.write(line)

    # Filter SEED database
    pass
```

I don't want to use process.Popen() or anything because I want this script to be platform-independent.

The problem is that the Gzip library only accepts filenames as arguments and not handles.  The reason for "piping" is that the download step only uses up ~5% CPU and it would be faster to run the extraction and processing at the same time.

---

**EDIT**:
This won't work because

> "Because of the way gzip compression
>   works, GzipFile needs to save its
>   position and move forwards and
>   backwards through the compressed file.
>   This doesn't work when the “file” is a
>   stream of bytes coming from a remote
>   server; all you can do with it is
>   retrieve bytes one at a time, not move
>   back and forth through the data
>   stream." - [dive into python](http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/gzip_compression.html)

Which is why I get the error

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'tell'
```

So how does `curl url | gunzip | whatever` work?

Comment: Why isn't this in separate Python files?  `python download.py | python extract.py | python filter.py`?

Comment: Because executing python scripts from system commands from python scripts is messy.  Also, I said that I want this to be platform-independent (meaning those people out there using Windows won't have any problems), and executing system commands makes that difficult.  Does DOS even support piping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just `gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=handle)` and you'll be on your way -- in other words, it's not really true that "the Gzip library only accepts filenames as arguments and not handles", you just have to use the `fileobj=` named argument.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't see that in the docu.

Comment: Python 2: an addinfourl object (as created by `urllib.urlopen`) does not implement `tell` which is required. Thus this answer doesn’t work there. (In Python 3, `http.client.HTTPResponse` does implement `tell`.)

Comment: Minor correction to @ChrisMorgan's note: Python 3's `http.client.HTTPResponse` doesn't implement `tell` either, but `gzip.GzipFile` supports nonseekable files as of Python 3.2. Either way, this answer works with `urlopen` responses in Python 3, which is wonderful.

Comment: @TreyHunner: it looks like `tell` was only added in Python 3.5 (which was about 7 months old when I wrote that comment, and which I had installed). https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects, “Changed in version 3.5: The io.BufferedIOBase interface is now implemented and all of its reader operations are supported.” `tell` is part of IOBase, which BufferedIOBase extends.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: the `tell()` method doesn't seem to work for me on the objects returned from `urllib.request.urlopen` in Python 3.7.

Comment: Hmm, `io.UnsupportedOperation: seek`. I dunno. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

A `python3` solution which does **not** require a `for` loop & writes the `byte` object directly as a `binary` stream:

```
import gzip
import urllib.request

    def download_file(url):
       out_file = '/path/to/file'

       # Download archive
       try:
          # Read the file inside the .gz archive located at url
          with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
             with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response) as uncompressed:
                file_content = uncompressed.read()

          # write to file in binary mode 'wb'
          with open(out_file, 'wb') as f:
             f.write(file_content)
             return 0

       except Exception as e:
          print(e)
          return 1
```

Call the function with `retval=download_file(url)` to capture the `return code`

Answer (score 2):

I've found this question while searching for methods to download and unzip a `gzip` file from an URL but I didn't manage to make the accepted answer work in Python 2.7.

Here's what worked for me (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352668/download-and-decompress-gzipped-file-in-memory)):

```py
import urllib2
import gzip
import StringIO

def download(url):
    # Download SEED database
    out_file_path = url.split("/")[-1][:-3]
    print('Downloading SEED Database from: {}'.format(url))
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    compressed_file = StringIO.StringIO(response.read())
    decompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_file)

    # Extract SEED database
    with open(out_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(decompressed_file.read())

    # Filter SEED database
    # ...
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    download("ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/fasta_files/RF00001.fa.gz")
```

I changed the target URL since the original one was dead: I just looked for a `gzip` file served from an ftp server like in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

for python 3.8 here is my code, wrote on 08/05/2020

```
import re
from urllib import request
import gzip
import shutil

url1 = "https://www.destinationlighting.com/feed/sitemap_items1.xml.gz"
file_name1 = re.split(pattern='/', string=url1)[-1]
r1 = request.urlretrieve(url=url1, filename=file_name1)
txt1 = re.split(pattern=r'\.', string=file_name1)[0] + ".txt"

with gzip.open(file_name1, 'rb') as f_in:
    with open(txt1, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```