# Download and decompress gzipped file in memory?

Tags: python, file, gzip, urllib2, stringio

I would like to download a file using urllib and decompress the file in memory before saving.

This is what I have right now:

```py
response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())
decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb')
outfile = open(outFilePath, 'w')
outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())
```

This ends up writing empty files. How can I achieve what I'm after?

**Updated Answer:**

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python2
import urllib2
import StringIO
import gzip

baseURL = "https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/"        
# check filename: it may change over time, due to new updates
filename = "man-pages-5.00.tar.gz" 
outFilePath = filename[:-3]

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO(response.read())
decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile)

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())
```

Comment: what's wrong with decompressing to disk?

Comment: I am decompressing to disk, just never letting the compressed bytes touch the disk.

Comment: does `compressedFile` ever get byes put into it?

Comment: Yes, in the updated version

Comment: unrelated: you could use `shutil.copyfileobj(decompressed_file, outfile)` to save the file chunk by chunk without loading it in memory.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to seek to the beginning of `compressedFile` after writing to it but before passing it to `gzip.GzipFile()`. Otherwise it will be read from the end by `gzip` module and will appear as an empty file to it. See below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import StringIO
import gzip

baseURL = "https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/"
filename = "man-pages-3.34.tar.gz"
outFilePath = "man-pages-3.34.tar"

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())
#
# Set the file's current position to the beginning
# of the file so that gzip.GzipFile can read
# its contents from the top.
#
compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb')

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())
```

Comment: Turns out I could have taken advantage of StringIO's `__init__`, see updated question.

Comment: Yeah. That works even better. :) I will leave my answer unedited as you've already added the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @OregonTrail: or you could cut out the middleman and [pass `response` directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279). btw, don't put *answers* into the question; [you are encouraged to post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 25):

For those using Python 3, the equivalent answer is:

```
import urllib.request
import io
import gzip

response = urllib.request.urlopen(FILE_URL)
compressed_file = io.BytesIO(response.read())
decompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_file)

with open(OUTFILE_PATH, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressed_file.read())
```

Comment: it won't work: you are trying to write bytes into a text file; use binary mode instead. Try: `copyfileobj(GzipFile(fileobj=response), open(outfile_path, 'wb'))`

Answer (score 20):

If you have Python 3.2 or above, life would be much easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gzip
import urllib.request

baseURL = "https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/"
filename = "man-pages-4.03.tar.gz"
outFilePath = filename[:-3]

response = urllib.request.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
with open(outFilePath, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(gzip.decompress(response.read()))
```

For those who are interested in history, see https://bugs.python.org/issue3488 and https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/3fa0a9553402.

Comment: Best solution so far.

Answer (score -3):

**One line code to print the decompressed file content:**

```
print gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(DOWNLOAD_LINK).read()), mode='rb').read()
```