# IOError when downloading and decompressing gzip file

Tags: python

I'm trying to download and decompress a gzip file and then convert the resulting decompressed file which is of tsv format into a CSV format which would be easier to parse. I am trying to gather the data from the ["Download Table" link](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file=data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz) in [this URL](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/irt_euryld_d). My code is as follows, where I am using the same idea as [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352668/download-and-decompress-gzipped-file-in-memory), however I get the error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file=data/irt_euryld_d.tsv'` in the line `with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:`

```
import os
import urllib2 
import gzip
import StringIO

baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?"
filename = "D:\Sidney\irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz" #Edited after heinst's comment below
outFilePath = filename[:-3]

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())

#Now have to deal with tsv file
import csv

with open(outFilePath,'rb') as tsvin, open('ECB.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout) #Converting output into CSV Format
```

Thank You

Comment: Why do you have `file=` in front of your path? Is that part of the directory name?

Comment: @heinst Sorry. I will rectify that. However, the error still remains.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the updated code so I can look?

Comment: @heinst Just updated it.

Comment: I know the problem, you need the full path to the data folder. so `/Users/path/to/data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz`

Comment: @heinst Thank You. So I changed the line to `filename = "/Users/path/to/data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"`, however, I still get the same error. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Well it has to be a valid path. Wherever the file `irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz` is you have to provide the full path to it. For example if I have `irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz` on my desktop, my path to it would be `/Users/heinst/Desktop/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz`. And I would set that path as the `filename` value

Comment: @heinst Thanks. I think that resolved the issue. However, I have another one now. Can I edit the question to reflect this?

Comment: Youll have to open another question for the new issue. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you were setting `filename` to was not a valid path to have a file written to it. So you have to change `filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"` to be a valid path to wherever you want the `irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz` file to live. For example if I wanted the `irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz` file on my desktop I would set the value of `filename = "/Users/heinst/Desktop/data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"`. Since this is a valid path, python will not give you the `No such file or directory` error anymore.