# IOError when decompressing gzip file

Tags: python

I'm trying to download and decompress a gzip file and then convert the resulting decompressed file which is of tsv format into a CSV format which would be easier to parse. I am trying to gather the data from the ["Download Table" link](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file=data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz) in [this URL](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/irt_euryld_d). My code is as follows, where I am using the same idea as [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352668/download-and-decompress-gzipped-file-in-memory), however I get the error `IOError: Not a gzipped file` in the line `outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())`. My code is as follows:

```
import os
import urllib2 
import gzip
import StringIO

baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?"
filename = "D:\Sidney\irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz" #Edited after heinst's comment below
outFilePath = filename[:-3]

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())

#Now have to deal with tsv file
import csv

with open(outFilePath,'rb') as tsvin, open('ECB.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout) #Converting output into CSV Format
```

Comment: You should probably output the first few bytes of the `compressedFile` and check it actually looks like a zip file. There's a few things that may be going on here, one possibility is that server is giving you an error page because your download request is missing a request param, or cookie, or it doesn't like the useragent. As a side note, I would highly recommend you look at using the Requests package (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib2.

Comment: Use a raw string for Windows paths:  `filename = r"D:\Sidney\irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"`.  Won't make any difference here, but a general comment for safety.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks. However, I still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you try to pull a wrong file
when checking the response in your code you get an html page of an error
you are trying to add your own path to the url which leads to a wrong url

```
import os
import urllib2 
import gzip
import StringIO

baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file="
filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz" #Edited after heinst's comment below
outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3]
response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
print response
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())

#Now have to deal with tsv file
import csv

with open(outFilePath,'rb') as tsvin, open('ECB.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout) #Converting output into CSV Format
```

the difference is the line for filename and a small addition to the baseURL 
filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"
which is the correct file name according to the link you specified

the other change is 
this line outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3]

which could be better written as

```
outFilePath = os.join('D:','Sidney',filename.split('/')[1][:-3])
```

Comment: Thank You. Just one question, did you mean `outFilePath` instead of `outFileName` in `outFileName = os.join('D:','Sidney',filename.split('/')[1][:-3])`.