# Curl to Python to download a GZ file?

Tags: python-3.x, curl, download, gzip, gunzip

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://sampleurl/sample.log.gz' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXTokenXXX' \
--data-raw '{
    "enabled": true
}' | gunzip -c
```

My requirement is to download a gz log file. The above is the sample curl which works as expected. How can I add this to python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Turns out there's a library dedicated to this exact problem. Here's the [gzip library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html), and a [stackoverflow post about this exact topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548495/download-extract-and-read-a-gzip-file-in-python).

---

Old answer: You may be able to do this using the [requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) by passing in [custom headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) as a dictionary, and then writing the content of your response as a file.

```
import requests
url = 'https://sampleurl/sample.log.gz'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXTokenXXX'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  # if the URL will redirect, include allow_redirects=True

with open('C:\\path\\to\\save\\to', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

You'll probably need to tinker around with that to get it working for your use-case (especially if that --data-raw bit is important), but that's the general idea. If you need to download a particularly large file or want to see some other alternative solutions, you can check out this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests).

Comment: Thankyou for the help.The above is writing the content in unreadable format , that means only the curl is working not gunzip -c option. How can I include that?

Comment: @NagasriVarma Turns out there's a library dedicated to this exact problem, which I would have found if I had done a better search. Here's the [gzip library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html), and a [stackoverflow post about this exact topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548495/download-extract-and-read-a-gzip-file-in-python) (which hopefully has a good enough answer). I'll edit my answer to include these